# Доступ к контроллеру CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, auth, php

Добрый вечер.
Подскажите, каким образом, через компонент авторизации можно запретить доступ ко всем действиям контроллера определенной группе лиц?

Пробовал в beforeFilter писать

```
if($user['role'] != 'admin')
    $this->Auth->deny('*');
```

ничего не выходит...
заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после логина в сессию возмем хранился id админа, в компоненте Auth пишем функцию

```
function checkSession(){
   $check =  $this->Session->check('Admin.Id');
   //либо $this->Session->read('Admin.Id');
   if($check){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
//а в котроллере
$check = $this->Auth->checkSession();
if(!$check){
   $this->redirect($this->webroot);
}
//или можно просто так,
function checkSession(){
   $check =  $this->Session->check('Admin.Id');
   //либо $this->Session->read('Admin.Id');
   if($check){
       return $check;
   }
   else{
       $this->controller->redirect($this->webroot);
   }
}
```

$result = $this->Auth->checkSession();

Answer (score 0):

Честно не знаю, как в cakephp это сделано, но в yii есть

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view','admin','update','create'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
}
```

Соответственно есть список экшинов, к которым могут обращаться те или иные пользователи.